# If he takes the later plane tonight he won’t have to rush

Tags: conditionals, irrealis-were

According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 88,

> if *took* could be the realisation of either
>   a preterite or an irrealis, there'd be no way of telling in cases
>   like [29ii] (*If he took the later plane tonight he wouldn’t have to
>   rush*) whether it corresponded to *was* or to *were*.

What two meanings (or conditionals as taught in ELT) does the sentence [[29ii]] have?

Comment: 1. If he were to take the later flight... 2. If he has taken the later flight...

Comment: @Jim what about _tonight_? and the apodoses would be different

Comment: BTW, Is the -ed form in _whether it corresponded_ grammatical?

Comment: I think the "ambiguity" of the cited example turns on whether the speaker's referring to the plane "he" *actually* took earlier, or a plane he *could* take in a hypothetical future. But focusing on ***was / were***, presumably what they're getting at is the difference between *If I **was** selfish, I apologise* (referring to a past fact: either I was or I wasn't selfish earlier, but *I don't necessarily know*), and *If I **were** selfish, I would keep everything* (implying that I'm not *actually* selfish, except in some hypothetical "irrealis" alternative to the present universe).

Comment: @FumbleFingers for your second interpretation, what apodoses would you use in the example of my post?

Comment: The "apodosis" (the clause identifying the "consequence" of the conditional clause) depends on whether that (truth value as yet unknown to the speaker) consequence lies in the speaker's past *(He **wouldn't have had** to rush)* or future *(He **won't have** to rush)*. Because of ***tonight***, we can't know which applies (but if that had been, say, ***last week***, we could be pretty sure it was the *first* of those).

Comment: @FumbleFingers _wouldn't have **had** to_ is still different fom the original _wouldn’t have to_

Comment: Yes, because *wouldn't have **had** to* forces the interpretation that the preceding "conditional" refers to *something in the past that speaker knows **didn't** happen* (as opposed to being an "open question" at time of utterance). Note that the (consequential) "need to rush" could be in the speaker's ***present*** - which could in principle be expressed by *wouldn't / won't **be needing to** rush [**now**]* - or the speaker's ***future*** *(wouldn't / won't need to)*. Some permutations are ambiguous, others not.

Comment: Note that I don't actually understand your Cambridge citation *if "took" could be the realisation of either a preterite or an irrealis, there'd be no way of telling* seems to imply that there ***is*** a way of telling. That's to say *if "took" could be* implies a "counterfactual" - *if that **were to be** the case [which in fact it isn't]* we'd be unable to tell exactly what *he wouldn’t have to rush* means. By further implication, since that's ***not*** the case, we ***should*** be able to tell. But ***I can't tell***, so I don't know what they're getting at.